# How to generate redirect url for Login link to IdentityServer url: https://localhost:5000/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I want to provide a simple 'Login' link on my website, but I'm unable to create a valid redirect url.

My link points to my IdentityServer4 /Account/Login page. How can I declare or generate a redirect url to my client website?

I've thought about simply pointing the login link to a page in my website that has to be [Authorize]'d ... which works, it does then forward on to the IdentityServer login page, but seems a dirty hack.

I've also tried to copy verbatim the url to the IdentityServer produced by this method, but not surprised, it fails with a "Correlation Failed" exception.

Here's the URL I am trying to use copied from an [Authorize] page redirect to IdentityServer, with the generated redirect string (separated for readability).

Localhost:44320 - IdentityServer

LocalHost:44390 - Website

https://localhost:44320/Account/Login?**ReturnUrl**=%2F**connect**%2F**authorize**%2F**callback**%3F**client_id**%3D**adminwebsite**%26**rediect_uri**%3D**https**%253A%252F%252F**localhost**%253A**44390**%252F**signin-oidc**%26**response_type**%3D**code**%2520**id_token**%26**scope**%3D**openid**%2520**profile**%2520**address**%2520**roles**%2520**authorisationlevel**%26**response_mode**%3D**form_post**%26**nonce**%3D637402012214631946.OTEyMjNlMzMtMWY4NC20OTQyLWE2NmQt2WMzOWUyMWE4NjdkY2E5nWNmZDUtYzc1Ma00MdI3LTkgMjEtMjr3NyA3YzFkYHZl%26state%3DCfDJ8MY7uAeD4GSDitRtFHe5rPR44JW3TF346c95Sa7_TN0hZjLGDaJyTWAFSHKTgouPov4fDyJEJc6FsOkcg1gOSu4MxY7cqu4N11vPi4f0wu-JpnfWQbbTbtasrhyU-zSf45_aLAvURKmvnlvgogfp_dF_Om5vMYdfsGlvVzgJsiRsvOUGxipsv_hMvCpXmx5ecDHmQvn3xiJVKs2vkzIxI64vuKxPYpMvx44MxgkxwSxv1vnxvHxvXFVLvRvXqVXdfXEN6fvSBT08yr-farVUXVsjXVC3ReaF_sHVXC-fYTXVDJJXl5Q2eCVX7VXCGVKJ7XCcelc-ZFUXVCfqOXC0%26**x-client-SKU**%3D**ID_NETSTANDARD2_0**%26**x-client-ver**%3D**5.3.0.0**

I simply want to declare a login link on my website that will allow the user to go to my IdentityServer, authorize then be redirected back to the same website page as before. I thought this would be a 5 minute job... I've searched all the IdentityServer documentation and google'd every permutation I can think of with no luck, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Your login link needs to issue a *Challenge* against the IdentityServer scheme.

Comment: Using the Authorize attribute is not a dirty hack.

Comment: Hi Ruard, just to be clear, I know the [Authorize] attribute itself is not a dirty hack... But if I create a blank login page (website side) with the [Authorize] attribute on that page, point my link to that, it will redirect me to the IdentityServer Login page. When it redirects after I've logged in, I go back to the blank login page on my website. I know I can do this and can make it work, but it seems messy, when all I want is a login link that will take me to the IdentityServer and bring me back to the original website page when done.

Comment: Hi Kirk, that sounds exactly what I need, do you know how I would issue that challenge without linking to another page?

Comment: @Craig Just point them at the homepage/entry point of your app. If they're not already authenticated then they'll automatically be redirected to your identity server to authenticate.

Comment: Hi Mackie, the website has some unauthenticated access, but I could point the link to a secured page, like the fake login page I've created on the website (which is just a blank page decorated with [Authorize]), but there has got to be a better way and unfortunately, I need it to redirect back to the page the user pressed the Login link too.

Comment: @Craig surely you could just have a secured "jump" action that forces authentication and then when executed redirects the user to wherever you need them to go?

Comment: @mackie I could if I was using MVC, but I'm using Razorpages so would have to do this at page level rather than a particular action, meaning I need to navigate away from the unauthenticated page that I am currently on. If navigating to a separate secure page is the only way to do this, then that's what I will do, but there has got to be a better way, hence my attempt at a direct approach

Comment: You can explicitly invoke the authentication scheme using the `HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(...);` method, does that help?

Comment: @Mackie - Superb, that's worked like a charm thank you.
If anyone is looking for the razorpage code it's Context.ChallangeAsync()

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I'm using the oidc js lib from my UI, so when I initiate a signin from the client, it redirects to [IdsrvUrl]/Account/Login?ReturnUrl="/connect/authorize/callback?authzId=xxx", and on login, returns to configured auth-callback pg passing returnUrl through. I'm now wanting to generate a link to my login page, and tried what was suggested here using ChallengeAsync, but it redirects to login page without the "/connect/authorize/callback?..." bit, causing my GetAuthorizationContextAsync to return null, and so doesn't redirect to my auth-callback pg. Any ideas?

Comment: @CraigM I know its a little late, but Id take a guess that your client declared in config in IdentityServer doesn't have the post login redirect url set.